# Changing the URL/ IP address of the AJAX function to be static

Tags: android, asp.net, html, ajax, url

Now, I have a web application made using [html, asp.net, sql server,javascript & ajax].
As usual I use ajax to send data to the server using the aspx page.
My Application is working fine, but I want to deploy it on Android.

The asp urls I use at the ajax function are:

```
 url:'http://localhost:49169/xxxxx.aspx'
```

As you can see, this won't be working on the mobile coz the url changes everytime.
So what should I do in order to change the url and IP Address to make them static & take the new configurations of the IP without recompiling the project ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _deploy it on Android_? Aspx needs .net runtime environment. Can you make it more clear what you are looking for?

Comment: I'll use phonegap for the deployement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon which version of visual studio you are using. But the general gist is that you can set the port from "using dynamic port" which it chooses one for you e.g. 49169  to a fixed port which you can specify.

Here are the intructions for vissual studio 2008, I believe it's the same intructions (or very similar) for other versions of visual studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer. I'm sorry I have another concern, if I changed all the urls, will I be able to deploy it on Android then? Or do I need to do another thing ?

Comment: Sorry @OnlyHope, looking at your comments on the question - I'm not really familer with phonegap. I'm guessing that typically phonegap would require a publically accessible site to generate it's app. But I'm not sure... perahaps phonegap have a way of creating test versions that work locally on your machine / network. However typically the built in webserver in visual studio won't allow remote connections. You could use "IIS Express" which does allow remote connections... but before looking into that I would check with phonegap's faq perhaps to see if you need a publically accessible URL.

Comment: No worries @OnlyHope, hope it helps.